# ¿Cómo instalar una aplicación de escritorio (hecho en visual studio 2019)y usar la misma base de datos en todas las PC?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, visual-studio-2019, aplicación-escritorio

He creado una aplicación en Visual Studio 2019, funciona bien en mi computadora y he realizado los pasos, que es conectar mi base de datos en otra PC y todo bien, pero la aplicación no funciona. ¿Cómo utilizar mi aplicación en otra PC y este pueda usar la misma base de datos?  Espero alguien me pueda ayudar. La base de datos lo realicé en Sql Server.

Comment: Cuando dices que _pueda usar la misma base de datos_, te refieres a que compartan una base de datos en común, donde ambas PC's ven y manipulan los mismos datos, o a que cada PC tiene su propia copia de la _misma estructura de base de datos_, pero los datos son independientes entre cada una.

Comment: En caso que la respuesta sea la primera, ¿las PC's están en una misma red local?

Comment: Asi es, en una misma red local y utilizando una misma base de datos, no independientes.